# Express.js is not reading sent data as string

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

I am building an application with the [MERN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack#Examples) ([MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB), [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js), [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)), and [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)) and I am sending confirmation data to my URL using a *put* request and checking if it is either: 'received', 'cancelled', or 'processing'. But the challenge is that I am comparing it as shown in the controller code below, but my function reads the values as different values even when I am sending one of the values I mentioned above. Below are my codes from my frontend to my backend.

UpdateStatus URL endpoint

```
// @Route   PUT api/orders/id/item_id
// @Desc    Route for updating order status
// @Access  Private
router.put('/:id/:item_id', [
    auth,
    body('newstatus','The new status cannot be empty').not().isEmpty()
], orderControllers.updateOrderStatus);
```

UpdateStatus controller function

```
// The controller for updating order status
const updateOrderStatus = async (req, res) => {
    const error = validationResult(req);
    // Check for errors in the body request
    if (!error.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json(error.errors[0]);
    }
    const { newstatus } = req.body;
    const { id, item_id } = req.params;
    try {
        // Get user account
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
        // Check if user account exists
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                msg: 'You are not authorized to make use of this feature.',
                status: 'unauthorized',
                status_code: '401'
            });
        }

        // Get the order data
        const order = await Order.findById(id);
        if (!order) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                msg: 'The order you are trying to update does not exist.',
                status: 'not found',
                status_code: '404'
            });
        }
        if (newstatus !== 'received' || 'cancelled' || 'processing') {
            return res.status(400).json({
                msg: 'Wrong purchase status detected.',
                status: 'bad request',
                status_code: '400'
            });
        }
        // Get order object
        const orderObject = order.goodspurchased.find(item => item._id.toString() === item_id);
        // Update order status
        order.goodspurchased.map(item => item._id.toString() === item_id ? item.status = newstatus : item);
        // Save order
        await order.save();
        // Get the vendor wallet
        const wallet = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM wallet WHERE store_id=$1',[orderObject.storeid]);
        // Check status
        if (newstatus === 'received' && orderObject.status === 'processing') {
            // Create new available balance and ledger balance
            const availableBalance = wallet.rows[0].available_balance + parseFloat(orderObject.cost);
            const ledgerBalance = wallet.rows[0].ledger_balance - parseFloat(orderObject.cost);
            // Update the vendor wallet balance
            await pool.query('UPDATE wallet SET available_balance=$1, ledger_balance=$2 WHERE store_id=$3', [availableBalance, ledgerBalance, orderObject.storeid]);
            return res.status(200).json({
                msg: 'You have successfully confirmed the receival of this product.',
                status: 'success',
                status_code: '200',
                order_status: 'received',
                item_id
            });
        } else if (newstatus === 'cancelled' && orderObject.status === 'processing') {
            let goods;
            if (order.goodspurchased.length > 1) {
                goods = 'items';
            } else {
                goods = 'item';
            }
            // Create new ledger balance
            const ledgerBalance = wallet.rows[0].ledger_balance - parseFloat(orderObject.cost);
            // Update the vendor wallet balance
            await pool.query('UPDATE wallet SET ledger_balance=$1 WHERE store_id=$2', [ledgerBalance, orderObject.storeid]);
            // Send notification sms to the customer that their purchase has been cancelled and their funds have refunded to their account
            await client.messages.create({
                body: `Hi ${order.customerfirstname} ${order.customerlastname}, your order for the purchase of ${order.goodspurchased.length} ${goods} has been cancelled and your funds are been processed. Thank you once more for using quickstore.`,
                from: '+12075033646',
                to: `${order.customerphone}`
            });
            // Return success response
            return res.status(200).json({
                msg: 'Your have successfully cancelled this order and your funds are been processed.',
                status: 'success',
                status_code: '200',
                order_status: 'cancelled',
                item_id
            });
        } else if (orderObject.status !== 'processing') {
            return res.status(200).json({
                msg: 'You have already confirmed this order.',
                status: 'success',
                status_code: '200',
                order_status: orderObject.status,
                item_id
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // Check for server error
        if (error) {
            return res.status(503).json({
                msg: 'We encountered an error while confirming your order. Please try again later, thank you.',
                status: 'service unavailable',
                status_code: '503'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

UpdateInvoice redux state mutator function

```
export const updateInvoice = createAsyncThunk(
    "order/updateInvoiceStatus",
    async (orderData, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const { id, item_id, data } = orderData;
            const response = await orderAPI.updateInvoiceStatus(id, item_id, data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);
```

OrderAPI.updateInvoiceStatus

```
export const updateInvoiceStatus = (id, item_id, data) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
        setAuthToken(token);
    }
    return axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/orders/${id}/${item_id}`, JSON.stringify({ newstatus: data }), headerConfig);
}
```

Invoice Component

```
import { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/layout/Header';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCancel, faCheck } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getInvoice, updateInvoice, clearOrderMessages } from '../reducers/orderSlice';
import SmallButton from '../components/layout/SmallButton';

const Invoice = () => {
    const [ goods, setGoods ] = useState([]);
    const { invoice, message } = useSelector(state => state.order);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { id } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getInvoice(id));
    },[id, dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (invoice && invoice.goodspurchased && goods.length === 0) {
            setGoods(invoice.goodspurchased);
        }
        if (JSON.stringify(message) !== '{}' && message.order_status !== 'processing') {
            setGoods(goods.map(item => item._id === message.item_id ? { ...item, status: message.order_status } : item));
            dispatch(clearOrderMessages());
        }
    },[dispatch, invoice, message, goods]);

    const updateStatus = (e, id, item_id, status) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = {
            id: id,
            item_id: item_id,
            data: status
        };
        // console.log(data);
        dispatch(updateInvoice(data));
    }

    const total = (goods) => {
        let cost = 0;
        if (goods && goods.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < goods.length; i++) {
                cost += goods[i].cost;
            }
            return cost;
        }
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ overflowX: 'scroll', overflowY: 'auto', marginTop: '10px' }} className='invoice'>
            <Header text='Receipt' />
            <table style={{ marginTop: '5px' }}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Serial #</th>
                        <th>Store ID</th>
                        <th>Product name</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Confirm/Reject</th>
                        <th>Price ($)</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Cost ($)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {goods && goods.map((item, index) => (
                        <tr key={item.productid}>
                            <td>{index + 1}</td>
                            <td>{item.storeid}</td>
                            <td>{item.productname}</td>
                            <td>{item.status}</td>
                            <td>
                                {item.status === 'processing' ? (
                                    <Fragment>
                                        <button onClick={(e) => updateStatus(e, invoice._id, item._id, 'received')} style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(3, 201, 53, 0.8)', padding: '5px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '0px', marginRight: '10px' }}>
                                            <FontAwesomeIcon style={iconStyle} className='clickable-icon-style' icon={faCheck} />
                                        </button>
                                        <button onClick={(e) => updateStatus(e, invoice._id, item._id, 'cancelled')} style={{ backgroundColor: '#F55050', padding: '5px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '0px'  }}>
                                            <FontAwesomeIcon style={iconStyle} className='clickable-icon-style' icon={faCancel} />
                                        </button>
                                    </Fragment>
                                ) : (
                                <Fragment>
                                    <button disabled style={{ backgroundColor: '#e3e6e7', padding: '5px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '0px', marginRight: '10px' }}>
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon style={iconStyle} className='clickable-icon-style' icon={faCheck} />
                                    </button>
                                    <button disabled style={{ backgroundColor: '#e3e6e7', padding: '5px', borderRadius: '5px', border: '0px'  }}>
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon style={iconStyle} className='clickable-icon-style' icon={faCancel} />
                                    </button>
                                </Fragment>
                                )}
                            </td>
                            <td>{item.price}</td>
                            <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                            <td>{item.cost}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td><b>{total(invoice.goodspurchased)}</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

const iconStyle = {
    color: '#ffffff'
}

export default Invoice;
```

Even when I send 'received', my Express.js backend still says 'Wrong purchase status detected.'. How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you attempting to convert the data to a string? Since you are converting your object `{ newstatus: data }` to a string when making the request with `JSON.stringify`, in your controller `const { newstatus } = req.body` won't work as you expect since it isn't an object. `newstatus` is undefined. In this case I would remove `JSON.stringify` in your axios request and just send the object with the `newstatus` attribute.

To make it easier for you to find these kinds of errors in the future I would add console.log right before the checking and see what value is causing it to enter that conditional. In your case since you mentioned you were getting the error 'Wrong purchase status detected.' that meant there was something wrong with your `newstatus` value.

I wanted to add this as a comment. Hopefully it will help you.

Edit:

If I wasn't clear enough: In your OrderAPI.updateInvoiceStatus simply change

```
return axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/orders/${id}/${item_id}`, JSON.stringify({ newstatus: data }), headerConfig);
```

to

```
return axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/orders/${id}/${item_id}`, { newstatus: data }, headerConfig);
```

Comment: This entirely depends on what's in `headerConfig`. If it has `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }`, OP's code should be working correctly even though it contains redundant transforms and headers